# SQLAlchemy alembic AmbiguousForeignKeysError for declarative type but not for equivalent non-declarative type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the following alembic migration:

```
revision = '535f7a49839'
down_revision = '46c675c68f4'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime

Session = sessionmaker()
Base = declarative_base()

metadata = sa.MetaData()

# This table definition works
organisations = sa.Table(
    'organisations',
    metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('creator_id', sa.Integer),
    sa.Column('creator_staff_member_id', sa.Integer),
)

"""
# This doesn't...
class organisations(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'organisations'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    creator_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    creator_staff_member_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
"""


def upgrade():
    bind = op.get_bind()
    session = Session(bind=bind)
    session._model_changes = {} # if you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, this works around a bug
    print(session.query(organisations).all())
    raise Exception("don't succeed")


def downgrade():
    pass
```

Now the query `session.query(organisations).all()` works when I use the imperatively-defined table (the one not commented out). But if I use the declarative version, which as far as I understand should be equivalent, I get an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join
>   condition between parent/child tables on relationship
>   StaffMember.organisation - there are multiple foreign key paths
>   linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a
>   list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign
>   key reference to the parent table.

Now I understand what this error means: I have two foreign keys from `organisations` to `staff_members` in my *actual models*. But why does alembic care about these, and how does it even know they exist? How does this migration know that something called `StaffMember` exists? As far as I understand, alembic should only know about the models you explicitly tell it about in the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my [Flask-script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) setup I was using to call alembic. The command I was using to call alembic was importing the code to initialise my Flask app which was itself importing my actual models.